# Question regarding an equality in a complex integral

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, contour-integration, complex-integration

I am working with the integral
$$\lim_{R\rightarrow \infty} \int_\gamma \frac{e^{i3z}}{z^2+4} dz$$
Where $\gamma$ is the contour $\gamma(t) = Re^{-it}$, $0 \leq t \leq \pi$ (the upper half of a circle in the complex plane centered at the origin and with radius $R$
).

Apparently it follows that
$$\biggl| \frac{e^{-i3z}}{z^2+4}\biggr| = \frac{e^{-3R\sin(t)}}{|z^2+4|}$$

I must be missing something obvious, but I cannot see how the equality in the numerators is deduced. Why is the real part of the contour being disregarded?

Comment: Use residue theorem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Rewrite the $z$ in the exponent of $e$ into polar form: $z=R(\cos t+i \sin t)$. Then notice that $|e^{-it}|=1$ for any real number $t$.

Comment: The equality is true if there is an $i$ in the exponent. Otherwise, its just the usual real valued exponential function $e^x$. Indeed, $|e^{it}|$ is a point on the unit circle for any real value of $t$, so it's modulus (absolute value) is always $1$. This of course is not true for the function $e^x$.

Comment: Got it now, thanks!